# Need for help about stm32f4 FW Package 1.26.2 bug

Tags: stm32

I have a problem with STM32F4 FW 1.26.2. When I  relocate the Vector Tab Offset in order to force the code to be programmed at a specific customized address, the generated bin file is not correct. At first I define USER_VECT_TAB_ADDRESS  in system_stm32f4xx.c then define VECT_TAB_OFFSET as 0x20000 which is a proper address for my code size. As I use Keil IDE I set the start address in the linker as 0x8020000. But when I build the project the generated file is not correct; its first address is from 0x8000000!!!

In previous FW package there was not this issue.

Could you help me?

Thanks.